# Audio through CAN FD into headphones

Tags: embedded, stm32, wav, can-bus, adc

I am trying to record audio using a 12 bit resolution ADC, take the sample buffer and send it through CAN FD to another device, which takes samples of this audio and creates a `.wav` and plays it. The problem is that I see the data of the microphone being sent through CAN FD to the other device, but I am not able to transform this data into a `.wav` file properly and hear what I say through the microphone. I only hear beeps.

I'm creating a new `.wav` every 4 CAN FD messages in order to make some kind of real time communication and decrease the delay, but I don't think  this is possible or if I am thinking it the proper way.

In this thread I take the message sent by the CAN FD and concatenate it in a buffer in order to introduce it in a `.wav` file. I have tried bigger buffers but it doesn't change the outcome.
How could I be able to take the data from the CAN FD and hear it?

Clarification: I know using CAN FD to transmit audio isn't the proper way, but it is for a master project.

```c
struct canfd_frame frame;
 CAN_MSG msg;
    int trama_can[72];
    int nbytes;
    while (status_libreria == 0)
        ;
    unsigned char buffer[256];
    // FILE * fPtr;
    int i=0,x=0;
    //fPtr = fopen("Test.txt", "w");
    while (1) {
        do {
            nbytes = read(s, &frame, sizeof(struct canfd_frame));
        } while (nbytes == 0);
        msg.id.ext = frame.can_id;
        msg.dlc = frame.len;

        if (msg.dlc > 8)
            msg.dlc = 8; //Protecci�n hasta adaptar AC3LIB a CANFD

        Numas_memcpy(&(msg.data.bdata), &(frame.data), msg.dlc);

        can_frame_2_ac3lib(&msg, BUS_VERTICAL);
        for(x=0;x<64;x++) buffer[i*64+x] = frame.data[x];
        printf("%d \r\n",frame.data[x]);
        printf("i:%d \r\n",i);
        // Copiar datos a fichero.wav y reproducirlo simultaneamente
        if (i == 3) {
            printf("Datos IN\r\n");
            write_wav("prueba.wav",256 , (short int *)buffer, 16000);

            //fwrite(buffer,1,sizeof(buffer),fPtr);
            //fclose(fPtr);
            system("aplay prueba.wav -f cd");
            i = 0;
            system("rm prueba.wav");
        }
        i++;
    }
```

[32 first bytes of the audio file being recorded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvX0o.png)

In the picture, as you can see, the data is being recorded. moreover, this data is the same data as in the ADC, but when I play it, I only hear noise.

Comment: To begin with you need to disconnect the real-time parts handling CAN FD from console I/O, system calls and other obvious bottlenecks. It would seem that this program would benefit a lot from multi-threading.

Comment: I have used the console I/O just to print the data I am getting out of the CAN FD reads, but it isn't what I expected. How can I play a wav without using system function using alsa? The major problem is that the data I get from the CAN FD buffer aint the same I see when I sniff with a IXXAT USB to CAN FD.

Comment: I don't know these libs but I know that you can't lock up a real-time serial bus while executing blocking PC-programming function calls. Audio will be very sensitive to such interruptions. Now if the actual problem is that you aren't getting the right values from the CAN bus then the problem could as well be with the sender. You need to use a CAN listener to monitor the actual traffic on the bus.

Comment: I am getting traffic in the bus, but when I try to read it using the second device it always take the same information and creates the same .wav. I am wondering if there is any possibility this is a format problem. Maybe I am trying to get the data out of the FD CAN in a wrong format.

Comment: UPDATE - The .wav file is being filled with the ADC data but it doesnt make any hearable sound, just noise.  In order to configure the ADC I have used the exact configuration of a demo of the STM32, but I dont know if the data that is being stored contains mcuh information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify the problem first.  Make sure you can transmit known data from one end to the other first at low rates. I'm sure the suggestion below will sound far too trivial. But until you are absolutely confident you understand it all, I predict you sill have many struggles.

Slowly - one frame per second, or even slower.

- Learn to send one 0x55 byte from one end to the other and verify at the receiver.
- Learn to send a few 0x55 in one frame and verify.
- Learn to send 0x12345678 - verify it ends up with the bytes in the right order at the other end
- Learn to send a counter. Check it at the receiver, make sure you do not drop any data.

Now do it all again but 10x faster.

Continue until you can send a counter at 10x the rate you need to for the audio without dropping any frames at all, for minutes and then hours.

Stress the rest of the system to make sure it still works under stress.

Only now, can you start to learn about sending audio.

Trust me, you will learn a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Ill try to implement the things you said! However, I have been able to prove that my ADC sends proper data to my .wav file and that I store them properly but when I make it sound it doesnt sound properly. I am wondering if this is a format problem, maybe in the middle it changes the endiannes or data size problem. Ill chek it out and if I solve it I will write down the solution.